# Tipo de lenguage de Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy utilizando por primera vez Reporting Services en Visual Studio y me tope con un pedazo de codigo:

```
=WeekdayName(DatePart("w",Fields!SalesDate.Value))
```

Alguien sabe que lenguaje es?

Comment: Se llaman expresiones, puedes encontrar mucha informacion de ellas en msdn:
[Expresiones (Generador de informes y SSRS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)